# No reaction for reciving SMS, BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm new in Android and I tried to receive SMS by my application. Sending SMS is working, so permission should work. First I wanted to show received SMS text in Toast, but I read it would be better to use Log. I'm using it and I not have any sign from BroadcastReciver.

I've tried to add receiver in manifest and Log for view is it working, but I not have anything in logs

MainActivity:

```
package pl.edu.pwr.student.a235420_ks_a5;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button importSimData;
    private Button sendMessage;
    private EditText smsMessagePhoneNumber;
    private EditText smsMessageText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        importSimData = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        sendMessage = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        smsMessagePhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        smsMessageText = findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        SmsReceiver myReciver = new SmsReceiver();

        Log.i("MAIN_ACTIV", "On create");


        importSimData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission is not granted
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO permission!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Add permissions in settings",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you have permission!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                    int phoneType = tm.getPhoneType();
                    int phoneCallState = tm.getCallState();
                    int phoneNetworkType = tm.getDataNetworkType();
                    String phoneSubscriberId = tm.getSubscriberId();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(phoneType),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(phoneCallState ),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf( phoneNetworkType),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, phoneSubscriberId,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //NO permission
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO permission!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Add permissions in settings",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
            else {
                //you have
                String phoneNumber = smsMessagePhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                String smsText = smsMessageText.getText().toString();

                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, smsText, null, null);
            }
        }
    });

    }
}
```

SMSReceiver:

```
package pl.edu.pwr.student.a235420_ks_a5;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String SMS_REC_ACTION =
            "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("SMS_RECIVER", "Recived Broadcast");
        if (intent.getAction().
                equals(SmsReceiver.SMS_REC_ACTION)) {

            Log.i("SMS_RECIVER", "Recived SMS");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[])
                        bundle.get("pdus");
                for (Object pdu : pdus) {
                    SmsMessage smsMessage =
                            SmsMessage.createFromPdu
                                    ((byte[]) pdu);
                    sb.append("body - " + smsMessage.
                            getDisplayMessageBody());
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS RECEIVED - "
                    + sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pl.edu.pwr.student.a235420_ks_a5">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.android.action.broadcast"/>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I would like to get text from incomming SMS in my app and show it in Log or better in Toast

Comment: You never request `READ_SMS` or `RECEIVE_SMS`. Requesting `SEND_SMS` is not enough.

Comment: I added it in manifest(like a permission and a Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED in <recieiver>) , is it not enough?

Comment: No, You need to explicitly request `RECEIVE_SMS` to start receiving broadcasts.

Comment: I modified in manifest to `<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">` and it work, `android:enabled` and `android:exported` were missing